# warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’

Tags: c, compiler-construction, warnings

So I'm new to C and am having trouble with whats happening with this warning. What does the warning mean and how can i fix it.
The code i wrote is here:

```
void main(void)
{
  char* name = "";
  int age = 0;
  printf("input your name\n");
  scanf("%s\n", name);
  printf("input your age\n");
  scanf("%d\n", age);
  printf("%s %d\n", name, age);

}
```

Answer (score 13):

The `scanf` function takes the *address* of a variable to put the result into.
Writing `scanf("%d", &someVar)` will pass the *address* of the `someVar` variable (using the `&` unary operator).
The `scanf` function will drop a number into the piece of memory at that address.  (which contains your variable)

When you write `scanf("%d", age)`, you pass the *value* of the `age` variable to `scanf`.  It will try to drop a number into the piece of memory at address `0` (since `age` is `0`), and get horribly messed up.

You need to pass `&age` to `scanf`.

You also need to allocate memory for `scanf` to read a string into `name`:

```
char name[100];
scanf("%99s\n", name);
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is this line:

```
scanf("%d\n", age);
```

scanf expects pointer arguments - this is the only way functions can modify parameters in C. In order to fix this one, you need to:

```
scanf("%d\n", &age);
```

Which passes the addressof age, which is now a pointer (a pointer is a variable containing an address to another area of memory).

As for this:

```
char* name = "";
```

Ouch-ow-please-don't! Ok, I need to explain. You've asked for a pointer to a character type, but as far as everyone's concerned, all you've got is a character, not a whole string. That's right, not enough space. Why does C let you do this? Well, C is basically portable assembler, so you can write wherever you like in memory (or rather, you can try and the compiler won't disagree, but the operating system can and probably will).

What you need to do is read up on memory allocation using `malloc` in order to allocate some space, otherwise I can input a massive string and it gets put at the address of name onwards.

This can, although by no means will, lead to stack-based vulnerabilities. What, *stacks?* Yes. A stack is a FILO structure and every time you call a function, you add space onto the stack for your return address and function arguments, as well as frequently function-scope variables.

Where this becomes a problem is if you don't check input sizes. Then, I can write massive values to your stack, including executable code... see [Buffer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

So how do I mitigate this, I hear you say, just yearning not to implement software vulnerabilities? You use functions that allow you to specify your buffer input size and read into a buffer of a specific size, and go from there. That's it. That simple.

See this question: [string reading in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424179/string-reading-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

You should write `scanf("%d", &age)`, as the `scanf` function needs to *modify* the value of `age`, hence the need to pass it "by address" and not "by value".

Answer (score 0):

It mean that it expect a "int *" (That is: A pointer to an integer) but you give it "int" which is an integer. To fix it add & to age in the scanf line so it become.

scanf("%d\n", age);

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming its complaining about the line `scanf("%d\n", age);` The issue is that scan f expects a pointer to your variable not the variable.  You need to get an address to variable by perpending a '&` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The warning means exactly what it says:  the compiler expects a pointer to `int` rather than an `int` in the `scanf` call.

Quick fix:  replace `age` with `&age`, and everything will work.

C passes all arguments by value, meaning that if you pass a variable only the value of the variable is passed.  The receiving function can modify that value all it wants, but the original value isn't changed.  To change the variable, you need to pass a value that points to the variable somehow, which in C is a pointer.

To get a pointer to a variable, prefix it with `&`.  To use a variable you've got a pointer to, prefix the pointer value with `*`.

In this case, you want `scanf` to change the value of `age`, so you need to pass it a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* name = "";
```

`name` points at a bit or memory large enough to hold a single null character.

```
scanf("%s\n", name);
```

You ask for a unknown number of characters to be read and stored at this address. *Anything* could happen. You *must* ensure `name` hass the address of a chunk of memory large enough to hold *anything* `scanf()` might read.

```
char twenty_bytes[20] = "";
scanf("%s\n", twenty_bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

hey friend recently means today I have also gone through this stuff.don't worry it's simple.

problem in the below lines of code :

```
scanf("%s\n", name);
```

and

```
scanf("%d\n", age);
```

you simply written these lines like printf() function. if you are using the scanf() function then always use **ampersand(&)** before the variable in the **scanf() function** because it's necessary. **&** is the **'Address of ' operator**, it gives the location of the number(address) used by the variable in memory.

your corrected lines of code:

```
scanf("%s\n", &name);
```

and

```
scanf("%d\n", &age);
```

Next time when you are going to writting this type of code or using scanf() function always try to keep in mind this stuff due to that you will not get the problem in your code.

Thank you for asking the question due that I also will not make such a mistake in the future while writing such type of code.