# Why scanf(%d-%d-%d) doesn't work and what does it expect?

Tags: c

I'm learning functions in C and i've got a problem.

It's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void equivalenza(int, int , int);

int main()
{
    int ore, minuti, secondi;
    printf("Inserisci ore, minuti e secondi (hh-mm-ss): ");
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", ore, minuti, secondi);
    equivalenza(ore, minuti, secondi);
    return 0;
}

void equivalenza(int ore, int minuti, int secondi)
{
    secondi = secondi + ore*3600;

    secondi = secondi + minuti*60;

    printf("\nSecondi = %d", secondi);
}
```

the output just doesn't start the function i think.

```
Inserisci ore, minuti e secondi (hh-mm-ss): 34-32-52

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 13.287 s
```

Comment: `scanf("%d-%d-%d", ore, minuti, secondi);` -> `scanf("%d-%d-%d", &ore, &minuti, &secondi);`. Most compilers will warn about that

Comment: Try to get in the practice of checking the return value of `scanf`. If you specify it should scan in three values, it should return `3` if successful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int \*’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751455/warning-format-d-expects-type-int-but-argument-2-has-type-int)

Comment: for more info on scanf `info scanf`

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the addresses of the variables you're trying to scan into.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void equivalenza(int, int , int);

int main()
{
    int ore, minuti, secondi;
    printf("Inserisci ore, minuti e secondi (hh-mm-ss): ");
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", &ore, &minuti, &secondi);
    equivalenza(ore, minuti, secondi);
    return 0;
}

void equivalenza(int ore, int minuti, int secondi)
{
    secondi = secondi + ore*3600;

    secondi = secondi + minuti*60;

    printf("\nSecondi = %d", secondi);
}
```

You should also check the return value of `scanf` and print a newline after your results. `int main()` should be `int main(void)` and the include of `stdlib.h` is unnecessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void equivalenza(int, int, int);

int main(void)
{
    int ore, minuti, secondi;
    printf("Inserisci ore, minuti e secondi (hh-mm-ss): ");
    if (scanf("%d-%d-%d", &ore, &minuti, &secondi) != 3) 
    {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    equivalenza(ore, minuti, secondi);
    return 0;
}

void equivalenza(int ore, int minuti, int secondi)
{
    secondi = secondi + ore*3600;
    secondi = secondi + minuti*60;

    printf("\nSecondi = %d\n", secondi);
}
```

If you compile with warnings on, you should receive warnings about your original code. E.g.

```
% gcc -Wall test.c
test.c:10:23: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", ore, minuti, secondi);
           ~~         ^~~
test.c:10:28: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", ore, minuti, secondi);
              ~~           ^~~~~~
test.c:10:36: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", ore, minuti, secondi);
                 ~~                ^~~~~~~
test.c:10:23: warning: variable 'ore' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", ore, minuti, secondi);
                      ^~~
test.c:8:12: note: initialize the variable 'ore' to silence this warning
    int ore, minuti, secondi;
           ^
            = 0
test.c:10:28: warning: variable 'minuti' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", ore, minuti, secondi);
                           ^~~~~~
test.c:8:20: note: initialize the variable 'minuti' to silence this warning
    int ore, minuti, secondi;
                   ^
                    = 0
test.c:10:36: warning: variable 'secondi' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", ore, minuti, secondi);
                                   ^~~~~~~
test.c:8:29: note: initialize the variable 'secondi' to silence this warning
    int ore, minuti, secondi;
                            ^
                             = 0
6 warnings generated.
```

Comment: Of 3 concerns answered here, the **key** lesson for OP is to enable all warnings.