# fscanf returning value of 0 - C

Tags: c, return-value, scanf

I have a file that looks like this:

> Kathryn 1561 2589.98
>
> Hollie 2147 2496.36
>
> Sherlock 3574 2514.65

and my fscanf - related code is as follows:

```
int load_data(char* fileName, char** accountNames, int* accountNumbers, float* amounts, int numOfAccounts)
{
    FILE *fPtr = fopen(fileName, "r");
    int counter = 1, test;

    if(fPtr  == NULL)
    {
            fclose(fPtr);
            return 0;
    }
    else
    {
            test = fscanf(fPtr,"%20s%d%f",  *accountNames, accountNumbers, amounts);
            printf("%d\n", test);
            while(counter < numOfAccounts)
            {
                test = fscanf(fPtr,"%20s%d%f",  *accountNames, accountNumbers, amounts);
                    printf("%d\n", test);
                    counter++;
            }

            fclose(fPtr);
            return 1;
    }
```

}

Here is the calling code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        int numOfAccounts = atoi(*(argv + 2));
        char* fileName = *(argv + 1);
        char** accountNames = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20 * numOfAccounts);
        int* accountNums = malloc(sizeof(int) * numOfAccounts);
        float* amounts = malloc(sizeof(float) * numOfAccounts);
        int dataload = load_data(fileName, accountNames, accountNums, amounts, numOfAccounts);
        dataload++;

return 0;
}
```

The if statement works, and the file is recognized. However, fscanf only returns 0. I'm really really new at C and fscanf so I ask that you be patient as I am learning, but if anyone could help me that would be great. Please let me know if I need to include more information. Thank you.

Comment: If you are really new at C, scanf might seem like a good idea.  It is not.  Read the file with fread or fgets or fgetc and parse the data yourself.  Do not bother with scanf.

Comment: @chux they should not be different, that's merely a typo.

Comment: You could check `ferror` and `feof` on `fPtr` and then check `errno` to see what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Note that code is always scanning values to the same location.  I'd expect something like `accountNumber + counter`.

Comment: @chux I have added the calling code

Comment: Should use `"%19s"` with `malloc(sizeof(char) * 20 * numOfAccounts)`

Comment: @muXXmit2X when I use feof to terminate my loop it repeats indefinitely.

Comment: @user3121023 no

Comment: Hmm I think `char** accountNames = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20 * numOfAccounts);` is a problem.  `accountNames` is a pointer to pointers.

Comment: @chux I wondered. The logic behind it is it's an array of strings, and each string is maximum 20 chars long, then we need as many strings as there are accounts. How can I fix it?

Comment: I'd go for allocating `numOfAccounts` `char *` pointers into `accountNames` and then allocating a 20 `char` for each.  The better approach would create a structure for `accountNames, accountNumbers, amounts`, but that may be beyond your current training.  IAC, strongly suggest reading the line with `fgets()` as @William Pursell commented [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682160/fscanf-returning-value-of-0-c?noredirect=1#comment68594686_40682160).  GTG

Comment: @WilliamPursell when I use fgets(*accountNames, 20, fPtr) my program immediately gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: Change this line test = fscanf(fPtr,"%20s%d%f",  *accountNames, accountNumbers, amounts);   to  this  test = fscanf(fPtr,"%s %d %f",  &(*accountNames), accountNumbers, amounts);

Comment: @LuckyAli that causes a compile error

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Your `char **accountNames` should be a 1D array, of length `numOfAccounts`, of type `char *`; and the memory allocation for `accountNames` is done in two steps, not one:

```
int anlen, ai;

accountNames = (char **) malloc (numOfAccounts * sizeof (char *));

anlen = 20;

for (ia=0; ia<numOfAccounts; ia++)
{
    numOfAccounts[ia] = (char *) malloc (anlen * sizeof (char));

}
```

Your `counter` can run from `0` to `numOfAccounts` rather than from `1` to `numOfAccounts`, so that you have only one `fscanf` statement, contained in your `while (count<numOfAccounts)` loop.

The string in your `fscanf` statement should be `" %19s %d %f"`. Note the spaces here, meaning 'ignore any leading whitespace'. This is one of the features that makes fscanf such a powerful and useful function, when used properly. Also, your `*accountNames` in your `fscanf` statement should now be `*(accountNames + count)` or `accountNames[count]`.

You may want to add a check that each name has been read, for example by inserting into your `fscanf` a `%c` to read the character immediately following the name on each line of the data file and checking this character using `isspace()`. If this shows an error, you might want to use, for example, the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545018/how-to-pass-variable-length-width-specifier-in-sscanf) to enable `fscanf` to read names of more than 19 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not advocating this approach but it seems to be what you're aiming for with your current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAME_SIZE 20

int load_data(char *fileName, char *accountNames, int *accountNumbers, float *amounts, int numOfAccounts)
{
    FILE *fPtr = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (fPtr == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = 0;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < numOfAccounts; counter++)
    {
        if (fscanf(fPtr, "%19s %d %f",  accountNames + (counter * NAME_SIZE), accountNumbers + counter, amounts + counter) == 3)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    fclose(fPtr);

    return count;
}

void unload_data(char *accountNames, int *accountNumbers, float *amounts, int numOfAccounts)
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < numOfAccounts; counter++)
    {
        printf("%s %d %8.2f\n",  &accountNames[counter * NAME_SIZE], accountNumbers[counter], amounts[counter]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numOfAccounts = atoi(argv[2]);
    char *fileName = argv[1];

    char *accountNames = calloc(numOfAccounts, NAME_SIZE);
    int *accountNums = calloc(numOfAccounts, sizeof(int));
    float *amounts = calloc(numOfAccounts, sizeof(float));

    int datacount = load_data(fileName, accountNames, accountNums, amounts, numOfAccounts);
    printf("%d\n", datacount);
    unload_data(accountNames, accountNums, amounts, datacount);

    free(accountNames);
    free(accountNums);
    free(amounts);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
% ./a.out test.dat 3
3
Kathryn 1561  2589.98
Hollie 2147  2496.36
Sherlock 3574  2514.65
%
```

Any time your code relies on parallel arrays, you're missing a proper data structure.

Answer (score 0):

OP's code has trouble with memory allocation and it shows up in file input.

The best is to isolate these 2 functions of code.

Given each line has 3 items: a name, number and amount, let us do that first.

There are so many weaknesses to using `fscanf()` [@William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell)
, going directly to `fgets()`  to read a *line* of text.  Then parse it.

Rather than OP's `"%20s%d%f"`, (which should be `"%19s%d%f"`, code below uses a more complex parse, yet flexible should the name size limit change.  Rather than checking the return value of `sscanf()`, this code checks the last parsed field.  Code could check both.

```
int Read_Record(FILE *istream, char *name, size_t name_size, int *number, double *amount) {
  // No need to be stingy
  #define LINE_SIZE 256
  char line[LINE_SIZE];

  if (fgets(line, sizeof line, istream) == NULL) {
    return EOF;
  }
  // %n saves the offset of scanning at that point.
  int n1;
  int n2;
  int n3 = -1;
  sscanf(line, " %n%*s%n%d%lf %n", &n1, &n2, number, amount, &n3);

  // If scanning did not complete or had extra junk on the line, fail
  if (n3 < 0 || line[n3] != '\0') {
    return 1; // parse failure
  }
  if (n2 - n1 >= name_size) {
    return 2; // name too long
  }
  memcpy(name, line + n1, n2-n1);
  name[n2-n1] = '\0';
  return 0; //success
}
```

To allocate memory for `numOfAccounts` records, best to use a structure.  As OP is a learner, let us do this without `struct`.

```
unsigned numOfAccounts = ...;
// TBD: Add test to insure numOfAccounts > 0

// Notice this style of defining the size needed - simple and clean
char **accountNames = malloc(sizeof *accountNames * numOfAccounts);
int *accountNums = malloc(sizeof *accountNums * numOfAccounts);
double *amounts = malloc(sizeof *amounts * numOfAccounts);
// TBD: Add allocation checks

for (unsigned i = 0; i < numOfAccounts; i++) {
  #define NAME_SIZE 20
  char name[NAME_SIZE];
  int rv = Read_Record(istream, name, sizeof name, &accountNums[i],
      &amounts[i]);
  if (rv != 0) Handle_Error();
  accountNums[i] = strdup(name);
}

// Use data

// free when done.
```

`float` is a weak choice for money.  `double` is better. [Many issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214586/2410359) with any choice.

Comment: `strdup()` is not a standard C library function, but common.  [Sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39694254/2410359)